# How to get file descriptor from Kotlin to C++ through JNI

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I want to access a file in C++ through JNI. For that, I'm trying to use Kotlin to open the file and then return the file descriptor. However, `outStream.fd` is not an integer, but an object:

```
    companion object {
        lateinit var context: Context;

        @JvmStatic
        private fun openFile(name: String): Int {
            val outStream: FileOutputStream

            val file: File = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), name)
            try {
                outStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                return outStream.fd

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
//...
```

How can I access a file descriptor from C++?

If there's a way to not even use JNI it would be beter, but I want to use the `getExternalFilesDir()`

Comment: Can't your C+ code open the file if you just give it the path?

Comment: Every java object is represented by `jobject`, and you use JNIEnv to access/interact with that.